# bash completion of full path files

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I've created the following bash completion function:

```
_scpinst ()
{
    local cur prev opts;
    COMPREPLY=();
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}";
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}";
    opts="-l";
    if [[ ${prev} == '-l' ]]; then
            files=$(ls /upgrade/*.tgz.gpg 2>/dev/null);
            COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${files}" -- ${cur}));
            compopt -o nospace
            return 0;
    fi;
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}));
    return 0
}

complete -F _scpinst scpinst
```

It automatically completes *.tgz.gpg files in /upgrade directory after a -l flag.
Is there a better way to accomplish it without using an 'ls' command. E.g. using -o filenames or -f ?

Answer (score 4):

Just use `-G globpat` compgen’s option:

```
COMPREPLY=($(compgen -G "/upgrade/*.tgz.gpg" -- ${cur}));
```

If by some reason you want to use exactly `-W wordlist` (e. g. to mix filenames with something else), this is also possible:

```
files=(/upgrade/*.tgz.gpg)
COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W '"${files[@]}"' -- ${cur}));
```

Both versions should properly handle filenames containing spaces (while your variant would not).

Comment: Ok. the 2nd one works well. The first acts oddly. it completes the filenames well, but when I type another char to choose from the files and hit TAB it will delete the added char.